# Redirect domain to a directory while retaining address

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have two domains (`example.com` and `example2.com`) that direct to the same location. I want to redirect one of the domains (`example2.com`) to a directory (`example.com/dir`), *without* any of the following occurring:

- Adress bar shows `example.com/dir`
- Adress bar shows `example2.com` but does not load contents of `example.com/dir` other than `index.html`
- `example.com` also redirects to `example.com/dir`

So that:

- `example2.com` shows the contents of `example.com/dir`
- `example2.com/page.html` shows the file `example.com/dir/page.html`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given that both domains point to the same document root, then you should be able to use this rule to rewrite `example2.com` to `/dir`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/$1 [L]
```

If that is not the case and they are not on the same servers, you will have to use `mod-proxy` `[P]` to accomplish this task. This would go on the example2.com .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/dir/$1 [P]
```